# Error creating bean with name springApplicationAdminRegistrar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have started getting below exception after I migrated project from Spring Boot version from 1.2.3.RELEASE to 1.3.0.RELEASE.

> Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException:
>   org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication

Stacktrace around this error is:

```
WARN  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:545 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter:449 - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:1480 - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userManagementDAO' defined in file [${PATH_TO_PROJECT}\target\classes\com\mycom\myproject\mappers\UserManagementDAO.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name 'getSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mycom/myproject/config/DAOConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mycom/myproject/config/DAOConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:1480 - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userManagementDAO' defined in file [${PATH_TO_PROJECT}\target\classes\com\mycom\myproject\mappers\UserManagementDAO.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name 'getSqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:1480 - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userManagementDAO' defined in file [${PATH_TO_PROJECT}\target\classes\com\mycom\myproject\mappers\UserManagementDAO.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name 'getSqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSqlSessionFactory': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:1480 - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleDAO' defined in file [${PATH_TO_PROJECT}\target\classes\com\mycom\myproject\mappers\SampleDAO.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name 'getSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mycom/myproject/config/DAOConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycom.myproject.entities.master.Method; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mycom/myproject/config/DAOConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycom.myproject.MyEntity
WARN  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory:1480 - Bean creation exception on FactoryBean type check: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sampleDAO' defined in file [${PATH_TO_PROJECT}\target\classes\com\mycom\myproject\mappers\SampleDAO.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'sqlSessionFactory': : Error creating bean with name 'getSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mycom/myproject/config/DAOConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycom.myproject.entities.master.Method; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getSqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/mycom/myproject/config/DAOConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mycom.myproject.MyEntity
```

Any pointer to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Context was loading manually(Java Code) from code for fetching a bean, removing which resolved the issue.
However my problem is solved but still not sure how it was working with last version of spring boot.